# Javascript property of the same name getting added when setting it in AngularJS service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, javascript-objects

I've got an AngularJS service that has a list of callbacks and a mutable property.

Whenever that property is modified using `setMutableProperty()`, callbacks are fired to handle the changed property.

The problem is, when the first `debugger` gets hit, the object ends up having two instances of `mutableProperty` in it.

```
angular.module('aModule').
service('aService', function() {

    var serviceSingleton = new function() {

        this.mutableProperty = true;
        this.mutablePropertyChangedCallbacks = [];

        this.registerCallbackToMutableProperty = function(callback) {
            this.mutablePropertyChangedCallbacks.push(callback);
        };

        this.SetMutableProperty = function(changeMutableProperty) {
            this.mutableProperty = changeMutableProperty;

            debugger; //this.mutableProperty == false here

            for(var i = 0; i < this.mutablePropertyChangedCallbacks.length; i++) {
                this.mutablePropertyChangedCallbacks[i]();
            }
        };

        this.GetMutableProperty = function() {
            var test = this.mutableProperty;

            debugger; //test == true!

            return this.mutableProperty;
        };
    };

    return serviceSingleton;
});
```

What the heck is going on here?!

Comment: Perhaps unrelated but Angular will `new` up the function you pass to `.service`. So I feel like you should be using `.factory` (which expects you to return an object, as you are doing), or you could simply pass the function you are currently `new`ing up to `.service`, instead of wrapping it in another function.

Comment: Also, what do you mean when you say the object has two instances of a property? Is `this` always the object it should be? How are `SetMutableProperty` and `GetMutableProperty` being called?

Comment: Attaching a debugger before and after the "this.mutableProperty = ..." line shows that the object now has an additional "mutableProperty" value. Mousing over it in the console in Chrome gives me:

"mutableProperty : true,
mutableProperty : false"

Comment: When you're on the debugger line type `console.log(this.mutableProperty)` into the console.  Believe maybe the hover over is just showing both the old and new values where it's being changed but after the assignment line executes it should have the updated value, also you still haven't shown the order of calling set/get with regard to what you comment on seeing in the code.